# Moving from buffer to an array for manipulation in Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, arrays

I am making a program to take data from a .txt document, I have used the BufferedReader method which goes through the document. It then prints the the documents contents into the console. I cannot however for the life of me figure out how to get the contents from the BufferedReader into a string array so I can then further manipulate it. Any help?

Comment: Can you post your code? This is encouraged even if it works as is. See the [faq] and [ask].

Answer (score 2):

The method [`Files.readAllLines`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) reads a file into a `List<String>`, one `String` per line in the original file. The method [`Files.readAllBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29) just reads a file into a byte array if that's your style. These are both part of the [Java NIO 2 library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html), part of Java SE 7.

```
Path myFile = Paths.get("hello_world.txt");
List<String> fileLines = Files.readAllLines(myFile);
```

Comment: I've added a concrete example that should work as-is.

Comment: This is probably the simplest approach for Java 7. +1.

Comment: Afraid it doesn't work. Comes up with errors on the path and the Files thing. :/ I'm doomed ._.

Comment: What errors? Are you using Java SE 7? (If not, you probably should be.) Did you remember to put `import java.nio.file.Files`, `import java.nio.file.Path`, and `import java.nio.file.Paths` at the top of your source file, just below the package declaration? If you don't know what this means, I recommend putting your project on hold and reviewing the basics. I don't mean to come across as rude, but you gotta learn how to walk before you can run ;)

Comment: I'm thrown redicolous assignments and I have been working that long I can't even think straight. All I seem to get is errors every time I ever try and it's wearing me down. I feel like I'm not even learning because it's just constant over difficult things or things not working like you'd think they would.

Comment: Does your prof or TA hold office hours? Those can be *super* helpful, and it's often easier to have a discussion and work something out there than in SO.

Comment: + it errors List and readAllLines

Comment: and also I'm a student. Not that I have any time to study any of the stuff I'm given because it's just "Here do this assignment" instead of "here have a few weeks to really get stuck in and understand"

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `String[]` array containing the lines of the document, you could use BufferedReader.readLine(), and stuff the lines into a `List<String>` instead of printing them.

Here's how you can create a list of Strings:

```
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And here's how you can add to it:

```
    String line = null;
    while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
        lines.add( line );
    }
```

Comment: How would I implement this ? I'm not the most amazing programmer, I'd just like to be able to 120% understand so I can do this again. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Do you want to hold the entire document in memory at the same time? Do you want to hold a list of lines, or a list of characters?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to read the document into an array so I can display it and manipulate it.

Comment: Do you want an array of Strings, or an array of characters?

Comment: I would like it as an array of strings if possible

Comment: Ah, then you can either keep your current loop, and add the strings you're already getting to a List<String>. If you're using Java 7, you can follow @Nick's easier approach. BTW, welcome to StackOverflow. You can upvote multiple answers by clicking the up-arrow to the left, and accept one answer by clicking the checkmark to the left. If you've got Java 7, I recommend accepting Nick's answer.

Comment: See the edited answer above for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

use DataInputStream instead of BufferedReader

```
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream (new FileInputStream ("myFileName"));
```

then you can store a String with methtod call is.readUTF ();

Comment: How would I go about doing that may I ask? thank you